# How to insert into MYSQL row from multiple $_POST arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms

I have a form with an "add contact" section, where upon a click, it adds another row to the form with 3 more input boxes. (The segment of code on jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fmdx/cYxYP/)

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="">
<div style="padding-left:40px;">
<div id="customcopies" style="padding-left:40px;">
1. Name: <input type="text" id="copiestoname_1" name="copiestoname[]" placeholder="Jane Doe Smith" required>, Institution: <input type="text" id="copiestoinst_1" name="copiestoinst[]" placeholder="Bank" required>, Method: <input type="text" id="copiestomethod_1" name="copiestomethod[]" placeholder="Email" required>
</div>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit_val" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

With this being the PHP/MYSQL for insertion:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_val'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['copiestoname'] as $key=>$value) {
    $copiestoname = mysql_real_escape_string($value);

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO copiesto (name) VALUES ('$copiestoname')") or die(mysql_error());
        echo "Completed";
    }
echo "" . count($_POST['copiestoname']) . " Names Added<br>";
mysql_close();
}
```

The table in the database is:

```
Table Name: copiesto
+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
| index       |  name       | institution | method  |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
```

How would I expand the current MYSQL code to accept entries from the other 2 arrays and input their data into the same MYSQL row during that loop?

Comment: Do you have a reason for using `mysql_query`? Is this a legacy application from the 1990s?

Comment: It's the code I've pieced together from examples and tutorials, sorry if it is a bit outdated!

Comment: what's wrong with this script?

Comment: I'd like to get the MYSQL code to accept the values from the other 2 input box arrays, inserting 1 value from each array into the row of the mysql database.

The code above only does the first array, but I haven't been successfully able to expand it to include the other 2.

Comment: @fmdx Learning from tutorials is an extremely risky way to go about learning PHP and web development as it will teach you all kinds of hazardously bad habits. A much better solution is to use a [popular framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) so that you can learn from good examples, plus make use of community developed add-ons that will snap in to your application without needing to be customized.

Comment: The thing is, that requires me to learn the framework.  Which, is a little late for my project.  Dear lord I hope I don't have to write much else beyond this little helper script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use for loop instead

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($_POST['copiestoname']); $i++ ) {
  $copiestoname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['copiestoname'][$i]);
  $copiestoinst = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['copiestoinst'][$i]);
  $copiestomethod = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['copiestomethod'][$i]);

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO copiesto (name, institution, method) VALUES ('$copiestoname', '$copiestoinst', '$copiestomethod')") or die(mysql_error());
  echo "Completed";
}
```

Comment: I get this error: "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"