# how to submit multiple data in mysql using php and jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

how to submit multiple values in a table please help me im using this code
this code submit only 1 entry in database but i want to enter multiples value in database how can i do this

live demo
http://jsfiddle.net/eruZC/3/

this is entry.html

```
      <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js'></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/css/result-light.css">

  <style type='text/css'>

  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function(){
    var id=1;

    $("#butsend").click(function(){
        $("#table1").append('<tr valign="top"><td width="100px">'+(id++)+'</td><td width="100px">'+$("#sname").val()+'</td><td width="100px">'+$("#age").val()+'</td><td width="100px"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a></td></tr>');
    });

    $("#table1").on('click','.remCF',function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
});
});//]]>  

</script>


    </head>
    <body>
      <form action="submit.php" d="form1" name="form1" method="post">
    <label>Student Name</label><input type="text" name="sname" id="sname"></br>
    <label>Student Age</label><input type="text" name="age" id="age"></br>
    <input type="button" name="send" value="Add" id="butsend"></br>
     <input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" ></br>
    </form>
    <table id="table1" name="table1" border="">
    <tbody>
    <tr><th width="100px">ID</th><th width="100px">Name</th><th width="100px">Age</th><th width="100px"></th><tr>

    </tbody>
    </table>

    </body>


    </html>
```

this is php page submit.php

```
<?php
/* 
 NEW.PHP
 Allows user to create a new entry in the database
*/

 // creates the new record form
 // since this form is used multiple times in this file, I have made it a function that is easily reusable
 function renderForm($sname, $age, $error)
 {
 ?>


 <?php 
 // if there are any errors, display them
 if ($error != '')
 {
 echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';
 }
 ?> 




 <?php 
 }




 // connect to the database
 include('connect-db.php');

 // check if the form has been submitted. If it has, start to process the form and save it to the database
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 { 
 // get form data, making sure it is valid
 $sname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['sname']));
 $age = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['age']));



 // check to make sure both fields are entered
 if ($name == '')
 {
 // generate error message
 $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

 // if either field is blank, display the form again
 renderForm($sname, $age, $error);
 }
 else
 {
 // save the data to the database
  mysql_query("INSERT stock SET sname='$sname', age='$age'")
 or die(mysql_error()); 

 // once saved, redirect back to the view page

 }
 }
 else
 // if the form hasn't been submitted, display the form
 {
 renderForm('','','','','','','','');
 }

         ?>
```

Comment: is it true that you are actually only inserting the values of the labels? The values of the names and ages that you append in the table is not a field and not part of the form in order to get submitted, to your php code. Also take a look here it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489046/how-to-pass-contents-of-an-html-table-as-form-data-on-a-post

Answer (score 0):

if u want to add multiple value from single form add comma seprated value in input box and then use explode eg:

```
 $sname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['sname']));
$namearray = explode(',',$sname);
foreach ($namearray as $sname){
 mysql_query("INSERT stock SET sname='$sname', age='$age'")
 or die(mysql_error()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try the .post() jQuery function ? it's very simple to implement

```
$.post( "example.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm", etc, etc, etc });
   .done(function() {
          alert( "second success" );
    })
   .fail(function() {
          alert( "error" );
   })
   .always(function() {
         alert( "finished" );
   });
```

Then in your php, you just have to insert into mysql with a loop like a foreach :

```
<?php 
       foreach ( $_POST as $p ){
           mysql_query( YOUR QUERY );
       }
       return ( 'DONE !' ); // your return values
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach` or `for loop` to execute multiple `insert` sql query.

You should `submit` your `form values` to get those values in `php` code.This question is exactly related to your question.
[How to insert into MYSQL row from multiple $_POST arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18665208/how-to-insert-into-mysql-row-from-multiple-post-arrays)

use your code like this fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/mPR45/

I hope this link will useful to you.